# Why is this finalizer running even when the finalized task is up-to-date?

Tags: gradle

I want to run transformations on my code quality reports so that I can have them in both human- and machine-readable formats.  I thought `finalizedBy` would be ideal tool to use for this because, according to [the documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#N11018):

> Finalizer tasks will be executed even if the finalized task fails.

… but …

> finalizer tasks are not executed if the finalized task didn't do any work, for example if it is considered up to date

However, I'm seeing the transform tasks running even when the tasks they finalize are up-to-date.  Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "findbugs"
apply plugin: "java"

repositories { mavenCentral() }

def findbugsJar = project.configurations.findbugs.find { it.name.startsWith("findbugs") }

tasks.withType(FindBugs) {
    reports {
        xml.destination "$buildDir/reports/${task.name}.xml"
        xml.setWithMessages(true)
    }

    def taskName = it.name
    def transformer = tasks.create(name: "transform" + GUtil.toCamelCase(taskName))

    it.finalizedBy transformer
    transformer.description "Transform report from $taskName into HTML."

    transformer << {
        ant.xslt(in: "$buildDir/reports/${taskName}.xml", out: "$buildDir/reports/${taskName}.html") {
            style {
                zipentry(zipfile: findbugsJar, name: "fancy-hist.xsl")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output of `./gradlew check` without source changes:

```
$ ./gradlew check
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:findbugsMain UP-TO-DATE
:transformFindbugsMain
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:findbugsTest UP-TO-DATE
:transformFindbugsTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

As you can see, `transformFindbugsMain` is being run even though `findbugsMain` is up-to-date.  Worse, this simplified test case happens to contain no test classes, so `findbugsTest` produces no output at all (Gradle appears to consider this "up-to-date", which seems reasonable enough, I suppose).  As a result, `transformFindbugsTest` bombs out entirely (the stack trace — omitted here for brevity — indicates that this is indeed the result of ant.xslt not being able to find the source file).

Am I misunderstanding the intended behavior of `finalizedBy`?  Is there something wrong with my build file?

I'm running Gradle 2.3 and Java (64-bit) 1.8.0_40 on Windows 8.

Comment: It would be quite big bug, could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @Opal — whoops; there was a typo in the build script.  It should now be runnable as a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Opal mentioned, this indeed looks like a bug. The next minimal gradle code will repro this problem:

```
task taskY << {
    println 'taskY'
}

task taskX {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { true }
    finalizedBy taskY
    doLast { println 'taskX' }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./gradlew taskX
:taskX UP-TO-DATE
:taskY
taskY
```

Per your specific case, then a possible workaround can be to condition the action on the existence of relevant file (`$buildDir/reports/${taskName}.xml`).

Comment: Well enough, then, I've [reported this as a bug](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/finalizer-tasks-run-even-when-the-finalized-task-is-up-to-date).  Thanks for the confirmation.